# How to prevent wordpress plugins from appearing on certain pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, function

I have noticed nearly every plugin once installed it shows/implement its codes (javascripts/css) within every page.

Is there any way I can use the function.php to exclude some plugins from appearing & implementing their codes on certain pages.

I have found this code but the plugins' scripts are still visible when I look into the page source code.

Help is really appreciated, thanks.

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'my_deregister_javascript', 100 );
function my_deregister_javascript() {
if ( !is_page('page name', 'or page id 30', 'contact-us', '67') ) {
wp_deregister_script( 'easy-fancybox' );
wp_deregister_script( 'slider' );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but you'll want to use `wp_dequeue_script()` instead, and hook into `'wp_enqueue_scripts'`. You also need to pass the multiple pages as an `array()`.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_deregister_javascript', 99 );
function my_deregister_javascript() {
    if ( !is_page( array('page name', 'or page id 30', 'contact-us', '67') ) ) {
        wp_dequeue_script( 'easy-fancybox' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'slider' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It did not work, the codes of the unwanted plugins are still visible on all pages, even when adding script extensions i.e easy.facncybox.script.js etc.